Unable to Authenticate dashboard into kiali with signing_key: "Unauthorized" Error Fetching Namespaces
Using the helm chart for setting up the kiali operator kiali/kiali-operator and configuring it to use the default signing_key I am not able to login with the value from the key and get a log message in kiali management console on login
ERR Error fetching Namespaces for local cluster [Kubernetes]: Unauthorized

Here is the CR config I made
cr:
  create: true
  name: kiali
  # If you elect to create a Kiali CR (--set cr.create=true)
  # and the operator is watching all namespaces (--set watchNamespace="")
  # then this is the namespace where the CR will be created (the default will be the operator namespace).
  namespace: "istio-system"

  # Annotations to place in the Kiali CR metadata.
  annotations: {}

  spec:
    deployment:
      cluster_wide_access: true
    external_services:
      prometheus:
        # Prometheus service name is "metrics" and is in the "telemetry" namespace
        url: "http://[REDACTED].svc.cluster.local:80/"
      tracing:
        # Enabled by default. Kiali will anyway fallback to disabled if
        # Tempo is unreachable.
        enabled: true
        health_check_url: "http://[REDACTED].svc.cluster.local:3100"
        # Tempo service name is "query-frontend" and is in the "tempo" namespace.
        # Make sure the URL you provide corresponds to the non-GRPC enabled endpoint
        # It does not support grpc yet, so make sure "use_grpc" is set to false.
        in_cluster_url: "http://tracing-platform-tempo.pit-system-apps.svc.cluster.local:3100"
        provider: "tempo"
        tempo_config:
          org_id: "[REDACTED]"
          datasource_uid: "[REDACTED]"
        # use_grpc: true
        # Public facing URL of Tempo 
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:3100/"
      grafana:
        enabled: true
        # Grafana service name is "grafana" and is in the "telemetry" namespace.
        in_cluster_url: 'http://[REDACTED].svc.cluster.local:80/'
        # Public facing URL of Grafana
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'
        dashboards:
        - name: "Istio Service Dashboard"
          variables:
            namespace: "var-namespace"
            service: "var-service"
        - name: "Istio Workload Dashboard"
          variables:
            namespace: "var-namespace"
            workload: "var-workload"
        - name: "Istio Mesh Dashboard"
        - name: "Istio Control Plane Dashboard"
        - name: "Istio Performance Dashboard"
        - name: "Istio Wasm Extension Dashboard"
      login_token:
        expiration_seconds: 86400
        signing_key: ""

I tried setting cluster_wide_access to true and accessible_namespaces to '**' and list every namespace in accessible_namespaces specifically. Nothing worked.
I have issues finding any more detailed log telling me exactly what the issue is, I assume the message in front relates to something else than what I have been debugging but I have no idea what it could be.
